# Highlight Skype window when I receive a message

Tags: linux, linux-mint, skype, cinnamon

I'm using Linux Mint 16 (Cinnamon desktop).

Is it possible to make Skype window be highlighted in the bottom panel when I receive a message (like on Windows 7)? I want to do this because sometimes I miss Skype messages, and I want to make receiving messages more perceptible.

This is how it looks on Windows 7:
[image]

I know that Cinnamon GUI is written in JavaScript. I'm pretty experienced in JavaScript, but I have no idea which files should I edit.

Or maybe I can just change some option in Cinnamon or Skype settings?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Do other windows highlight for you? Because for skype it seems to work fine in other window managers.

Comment: @JanHudec I've installed Linux Mint a few weeks ago, and for this time I've never seen any window is highlighting

Comment: Than it's generic problem of the Cinnamon interface; for me Skype highlights in the task just fine (in KDE) and so do many other programs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found a solution. I had to edit 2 JavaScript files:

### 1) /usr/share/cinnamon/applets/window-list@cinnamon.org/applet.js:

Find these lines:

```
this.actor._delegate = this;
this.actor.connect('button-release-event', Lang.bind(this, this._onButtonRelease));

this.metaWindow = metaWindow;
```

and paste this line after them:

```
metaWindow.actor = this.actor;
```

### 2) /usr/share/cinnamon/js/ui/windowAttentionHandler.js:

After this line:

```
_onWindowDemandsAttention : function(display, window) {
```

paste these ones:

```
    if (window && !window.has_focus() && window.get_wm_class() && window.get_wm_class().indexOf("Skype") > -1) {
        window.actor.add_style_class_name("window-list-item-demands-attention");
    }
```

Then hit `ALT+F2`, and enter `r` command. Cinnamon will be restarted. It takes about 10 seconds.

This is what you have to do. Now when you receive a message the dialog window should be highlighted with red color (so the dialog window must be opened, otherwise nothing will be highlighted)

This is how it looks like now:
[image]

### Attention!!!

My Cinnamon version is 2.0.14. If you have another version (type `cinnamon --version` in terminal), it might not work, or the system might crash. If it happens, revert all changes in those 2 files and restart Cinnamon (or computer)

Answer (score 0):

not possible. according to glebihan linuxmint developer:

> <~glebihan> it would have to be modified on skype's side, nothing that can be done in cinnamon

Comment: glebihan is possibly misinformed in thinking that Skype does not implement window attention. Skype seems to implement it as seen from its behaviour with other WMs.